# Android contact data is gibbrish when added throught intent

Tags: android, encoding, android-contacts

I have an intent which opens the create contact screen on android. When I try and add a contact with hebrew char' the charterers on the create contact screen appear as question marks(????)

I have tried encoding the name as utf-8 but I didn't solve my problem and has shown me the name as %X chars instead on hebrew

This is my attempt:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION);
                intent.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
                try {
                    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, new String(vcard.getName().getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "utf-8"));
                    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, vcard.getPhoneNumber()).putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE_TYPE, 0);
                    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL, vcard.getEmail()).putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL_TYPE, 0);
                    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.COMPANY, vcard.getCompany());
                    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.JOB_TITLE, vcard.getTitle());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

all the fields which contain hebrew letters currently appear as "????" I had trouble finding solutions on the web and the ones I did, did not fit.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how `vcard` is implemented, but I assume `vcard.getName()` returns a string.

What you're doing here is like saying: take the String name, **convert** it to `ISO-8859-1`, and then **interpret** those bytes as `utf-8`.

This usually just works:

```
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, vcard.getName());
```

If it doesn't work, try this:

```
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, new String(vcard.getName().getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: is it possible the vcard itself already contains the bad encoding?
can you download it as a file, and examine the file to see it contains the proper strings?